# Evaluation of :$\lim_{n\to \infty} {(1+\frac{1}{\arctan(n)}})^{\arctan(n)}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, exponentiation, inverse-function

Really i'm interesting to trigonometric form which is   related to :$\lim_{n\to \infty} {(1+\frac{1}{n}})^{n}$  , Wolfram alpha  show  that this: $\lim_{n\to \infty} {(1+\frac{1}{\arctan(n)}})^{\arctan(n)}$ equal to $(\frac{2+\pi}{\pi})^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(1%2B1%2Farctan(n))%5E(arctan(n)),+n++to+infty) , I have tried the variable change $y=\arctan(n)$ to get the same form with $\lim_{n\to \infty} {(1+\frac{1}{n}})^{n}$ but I didn't succeeded , Then Is there any simple  way to evaluate :$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {(1+\frac{1}{\arctan(n)}})^{\arctan(n)}$$

Comment: The WolframAlpha result is just a consequence of the fact that $\arctan(n) \to \pi/2$.

Comment: The limit with the arctangent is not related to the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$. The first follows from the arithmetic properties of limits (not an indeterminate form), while the latter is an indeterminate form (in other words one that doesn't follow from the arithmetic properties of limits, at least not in the order implied by the operations explicitly written in it).

Comment: Just i have tried to do transformation to it in order to use exp

Comment: @zeraouliarafik But this has nothing to do with $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n$, since $\arctan(n)$ is bounded.

Comment: Then wolfram alpha claimed it wrong

Comment: @zeraouliarafik No, WolframAlpha is completely right with the evaluation of the limit.

Comment: It's $\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^{\pi/2}$. So Wolfram is correct. What do you mean "Wolfram claimed it wrong?"  @zeraouliarafik

Comment: I'm sure that wolfram alpha used lim f^g =limit f^ limit g  , but why this valid in this case ?

Comment: Because there are no indeterminate forms here. You might as well just ask for $$\lim_{y \to \pi/2} (1 + 1/y)^y$$ which is much easier to think about.

Comment: As T. Bongers pointed out $\arctan(n)$ is bounded, so you cannot replace it for $n$, which is unbounded, in  $(1+1/n)$ and take the limit to give $e$. In fact both $\arctan(n)\to\pi/2$ giving the result you got.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$A=\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan ^{-1}(n)}\right)^{\tan ^{-1}(n)}\implies \log(A)={\tan ^{-1}(n)}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan ^{-1}(n)}\right)$$ Now, using Taylor expansion for large $n$
$$\tan ^{-1}(n)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$1+\frac{1}{\tan ^{-1}(n)}=\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\right)+\frac{4}{\pi ^2 n}+\frac{8}{\pi ^3
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan ^{-1}(n)}\right)=\log \left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\right)+\frac{4}{\pi  (2+\pi ) n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log(A)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log \left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\right)+\frac{\frac{2}{2+\pi }-\log
   \left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\right)}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ So, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \log(A)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log \left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\right)\implies \lim_{n\to \infty} A=\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\right)^{\pi /2}$$

Comment: This seems like a lot of work for the fact that the argument for the limit can be written as the composition of two functions with well-behaved limits, no? Specifically, taking $f(n) = (1+1/n)^n$ and $g(n) = \arctan n$ and $\lim f(g(n)) = \lim f(\pi/2) = f(\pi/2)$ by the continuity of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @Nitin. I totally agree with you. What I wanted to show is that, using Taylor, we can get the limit but also how it is approached.